# How to look up an object in vector in mit-scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

Version of MIT-Scheme: Release 9.2

I know in `list`, we could look up an object using `assv` or functions alike. I wonder if there is similar functions when trying to look up an object in `vector`. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general searching, you can use `vector-index` from [SRFI 43](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-43/srfi-43.html) to search for the index of a matching object.

`assv` and the like are for searching an *association list* (alist) for the given key. Vectors are almost never used for the same purpose as alists, not least because they're unresizeable. So naturally, there would be no `assv` analogue for `vector`.